# Activity не видит RemoteViews

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. У меня проблема. Я вставил данный код:

```
RemoteViews remoteView = 
    new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_message);
```

но почему то у меня красным подмечено context. Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Если поставить курсор на подсвеченное, то будет написано в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что там нужен контекст. Он может быть this или getActivity если это фрагмент